# Can't update parent state from child using functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an issue with my React app. I am trying to set the state of the parent component based on the child component's value. I can see in the dev tools and log window that the child's value is being received by the parent; however, the setState is not working as it should. I have tried creating a separate function just to set the values; hoping for it to act as a middleware but no luck.

I have been through about a couple of StackOverflow threads but not many cater for functional components. I found the following codegrepper snippet for reference but it does not help either.

link: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/react+function+component+state

Most of the threads deal with how to get the value to the parent component; however, my issue is more "setting the state" specific.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Character from "../component/Character";
import Filter from "../component/Filter";
import Pagination from "../component/Pagination";
import axios from "axios";
import "./Home.css";

const Home = (props) => {

    const [API, setAPI] = useState(`https://someapi.com/api/character/?gender=&status=&name=`);
    const [characterData, setCharacterData] = useState([]);
    const [pagination, setPagination] = useState(0);

    const makeNetworkRequest = (data) => {
        setAPI(data);
        setTimeout(() => {
            axios.get(data).then(resp => {
                setPagination(resp.data.info)
                setCharacterData(resp.data.results)
            })
        }, 1000)
    }

    const handleFormCallBack = (childData) => {
        setAPI(childData);
        makeNetworkRequest(API);
        console.log(`Parent handler data ${childData}`)
        console.log(`Parent handler API ${API}`)
    }
     
    useEffect(() => {
        makeNetworkRequest(API)
    }, [characterData.length]);


    const mappedCharacters = characterData.length > 0 ? characterData.map((character) => <Character key={character.id} id={character.id} alive={character.status} /* status={<DeadOrAlive deadoralive={character.status} /> }*/ gender={character.gender} name={character.name} image={character.image} />) : <h4>Loading...</h4>

    return (
        <div className="home-container">
            <h3>Home</h3>
            <Filter parentCallBack={handleFormCallBack} />
            <div className="characters-container">
                {mappedCharacters}
            </div>
            {/* <Pagination pages={pagination.pages}/> */}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

In the code above I am using a callback function on the parent named "handleFormCallBack", mentioned again below to get the information from the child filter component. When I log the value, the following results are being generated.

```
const handleFormCallBack = (childData) => {
        setAPI(childData);
        makeNetworkRequest(API);

        console.log(`Parent handler data ${childData}`) 
        // Parent handler data https://someapi.com/api/character/?gender=&status=&name=charactername

        console.log(`Parent handler API ${API}`) 
        // Parent handler API https://someapi.com/api/character/?gender=&status=&name=

    }
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but any sort of help would be much appreciated.

Kind Regards

Comment: It looks like you need a separate `useEffect` to catch the changes to `API` which would then call `makeNetworkRequest`. Note also that you can't log the changes to state immediately after you've changed it. State updates tend to be batched and processed asynchronously so that would be another use for `useEffect`.

Comment: Hi Andy, I tried that, I even tried increasing the timeout, but the app is adamant about not setting the state. Additionally, thanks for bringing the "asynchronous" functionality's point, based on my understanding, setTimeout should have catered for it; however, it didn't do much. Do you reckon using ref could possibly help the situation?

Answer (score 0):

**useState** works pretty much like **setState** and it is not synchronous, so when you set the new value using ***setAPI(childData);*** react is still changing the state and before it actually does so both of your console.log() statements are being executed.

Solution - after setting the new value you need to track if it has changed, so use a **useEffect** hook for the endpoint url and then when it changes do what you want.

```
useEffect(() =< {
  // do anything you want to here when the API value changes. you can also add if conditions inside here.
}, [API])
```

Just to check what I have explained, after calling ***setAPI(childData);*** add a setTimeout like

setTimeout(() => {
// you will get new values here. this is just to make my point clear

console.log(`Parent handler data ${childData}`)

console.log(`Parent handler API ${API}`)

}, 5000);

Comment: Hi Kishan, Thanks for the input; it is similar to what Andy suggested, but it didn't quite help the situation. Adding the effect function and increasing the timeout duration just increased the initial and later API request duration. The issue is that no matter how long I wait, I can't see the state is being set in "React dev tools".